# When creating a push notification channel using the Google Drive API (v3) does setting payload to true in the request body do anything?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to receive metadata or a summary of changes in my push notifications from the Google Drive API.

It would appear from the documentation that setting `payload` to `true` in the request body would accomplish this. As far as I can see, both file and change notifications do not include a request body even when `payload` is set to `true` when the notification channel is created.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/watch) states that `payload` is "A Boolean value to indicate whether payload is wanted. Optional."

Does anyone have any idea what this field does (if anything) and whether there is a way to include additional information?

Answer (score 0):

If we check with other Google APIs with similar `payload` request usage, it looks like a flag to determine if the message body should be included in the notifications.

Take a look at the [Google Admin SDK Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push), its almost similar with Drive API push notification is doing.

Comment: I filed an issue and Google accepted it as a documentation defect. I'm guessing they just didn't implement this for Drive. The way you described it is how I expected it to work.

Comment: Its probably just the phrasing on the documentation, but I believe its how they intended it to work. If it would help, their [Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) should work hand-in-hand with the [Changes] API. Happy coding!